# Reading from text-file with namedtuple entries

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a problem. I had a list consisting of namedtuples. I wrote this list to a file.txt. Now i want to read it back. I found out here that json is recommended for converting it beforehand and than saving it. But I need a solution for my already saved file. My textfile looks like this:

```
file.txt:

[Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]
[Hello(i=1, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]
[Hello(i=2, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]
[Hello(i=3, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]
```

If i use the split-method, it is almost as I want it to be, but as expected as strings:

```
lines = input_data.split('\n')
lines
['[Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]','[Hello(i=1,...),...],...]']
```

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Please use comments to give feedback to answers; question posts are just there for the question. Answerers don’t get a notification for edits made to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I hate promoting `eval()`, this must be one of those rare cases when any alternative solution is even worse.

```
line = "[Hello(i=3, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0)]"
# Original definition, I assume
Hello = namedtuple('Hello', ['i','time','x','y'])
data = eval(line)
#[Hello(i=3, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0)]
```

**NB** You should not use `eval` in any situation when the data that you read was not previously produced and saved by *yourself*.

Comment: I disagree that the alternatives are worse. Rather strongly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It depends on the definition of "worse," which is opinion-based :)

Comment: No, there are objective criteria: `eval()` brings a security risk that is not needed in this context, because the input is perfectly regular and can thus be parsed with dedicated tools.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since the data were previously saved by the OP, this is _exactly_ the context in which `eval` does not bring any security risks.

Comment: There is also the *future* security risks that `eval()` poses when taught without further context to new programmers. **Always** include the full picture and always try to find alternatives. Unless someone fully understands what `eval()` does and doesn't do, it should be avoided. Just like cryptography and SQL without parameters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's exactly how I feel and how I treat `eval`. However, in _this particular case_ any attempt to reimplement "restricted eval()" is superfluous.

Comment: Where is there a need to implement a restricted eval()? The pattern in perfectly regular.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I call a "restricted eval()". Anyway, with an added note that the proposed solution is limited only to this and similar special cases, I am afraid this discussion becomes religious.

Comment: Restricted eval, to me, is [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which parses valid Python into an abstract syntax tree, then interprets that syntax tree to produce Python objects and limits what kind of objects can be created that way. So it supports a limited subset of Python, giving you arbitrary evaluation of that subset. And sure, this is like using globals or goto. I'd rather teach professional developers to just stay the hell away.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunately, `literal_eval` does not parse namedtuples. You are right about professional _devlopers_, but the OP simply wants to read back the previously saved data. Sometimes it just makes sense to be pragmatic.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to parse your file as text, and extract the information using text manipulation techniques.

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) here:

```
import re

hello_pattern = re.compile(r'Hello\(i=(\d+), time=(\d+), x=(\d+), y=(\d+)\)')
```

This pattern matches the representation of your namedtuple values, and gives you access to the numbers for each values, albeit as strings:

```
>>> line = '[Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0),...]'
>>> hello_pattern.findall(sample)
[('0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '0')]
```

You can then convert those strings to integers again and recreate the instances; for a single line the list comprehension would be:

```
[Hello(*map(int, match)) for match in hello_pattern.findall(line)]
```

and a demo of this on the same line:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Hello = namedtuple('Hello', 'i time x y')
>>> [Hello(*map(int, match)) for match in hello_pattern.findall(sample)]
[Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0), Hello(i=0, time=0, x=0, y=0)]
```

So the complete solution would be:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

Hello = namedtuple('Hello', 'i time x y')  # or import your own ready definition
hello_pattern = re.compile(r'Hello\(i=(\d+), time=(\d+), x=(\d+), y=(\d+)\)')

data = []
with open('file.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        recovered = [
            Hello(*map(int, match))
            for match in hello_pattern.findall(line)
        ]
        data.append(recovered)
```